# Why " Live Sass Compiler " extension is compiling all sass files?

Tags: css, sass

I am new to coding and stack overflow as well. All I know is if you ever run into any coding problem go to StackOverflow and there somebody will definitely help you. So I recently got a problem with sass compiling. I am using Ritwik Dey's " live sass compiler ' extension to compile my partial .scss files but I am stuck here -

Edit 1 : Just got to know that I can't upload images yet! Please watch this >

[Issue gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw1T0.gif)

So here as you can see my main.css file had around 244 lines of code and I was working on this file. But as soon as I compiled my _grid.scss file, it gave me some errors. Now I don't know about these errors. But it is not compiling properly and increasing my main.css file every time. I don't know where these lines of code are coming from. But I do think that it is compiling every sass file which I have in other folders.

I am working on the file from " starter " folder. But I think it is compiling sass files from " final-S05 " and " final-after-S06 " as well ?

Is this the issue? If so, then how can I solve it?

Any help would be highly appreciable!

Comment: You’re going to need to add more info - we need actual errors, code etc… how are we suppossed to help? We’re not looking at your screen, let alone your code…

Comment: I have put a gif explaining errors. Will it work?

Comment: No, the gif is small and blurry. Best to paste the offending code here if you want help!

Comment: First : Do you want to skip error or solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks a lot for your responses [Kevin M. Mansour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14945696) and [somethinghere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619). I just got to know the rookie mistakes I have been making in my code.

So the first mistake was the save location path was ill-defined by me in the compiler extension. `"savePath": "/starter/compiled css"` this is the correct one. I don't remember what I was putting here before. Actually, I was confused regarding `/` this slash. So now I know that it took us to the root folder and from there on we can specify the location where we want to save our files.

And the other mistake was a typo error in importing the partial `button.scss` file. I was importing using this syntax `@import "components/button.scss";` which was absolutely wrong. So I corrected it `@import "components/button";` in my `main.scss` file and it worked.